# Bootstrap Modal Suggestion

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I'm using the code below 7 times in the body of my main html page to load html content into twitter-bootstrap modals.

```
 <div class="modal-body">
          <iframe width="900px" height="380px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" src="index.html#"></iframe>
 </div>
```

Loading this page takes about 30 seconds because its attempting to load all iframe content first, in each modal then it finally loads the page. I tried loading with jquery so that the iframe content loads into the modal on.click, but then when the modal opens the content for that modal takes forever to load.  Any suggestions?  Thanks

Comment: You're essentially asking us how to make 8 web pages load simultaneously and fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `iframe`s, use [Bootstrap API](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) [which relies on `$.load()`]:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal">Click me</a>
```

Comment: this is the quickest solution to load the page, but the modal html content still loads slow, I guess its just a performance issue with where my content is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

You could append the iframe to the modal-body using $(document).ready() event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#modal-body").append("[insert iframe here]")
});
```

Comment: appending just keeps layering content.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you attempting to load so many iframes at once? Try loading that content into hidden containers in the DOM.